# Qml Particles & Canvas

Tags: canvas, qml, particles

I made this situations as simple as possible: I am creating Item/Window/Rectangle/whatever that contains customized particle system.

```
Window {
    MyParticles {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

And I have also an item that uses canvas inside itself:

```
  Item {
        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') //without that line everything works fine
                //nothing further
            } 
        }
}
```

If I have them together (inside one parent, inside different parents that have one common parent), Particle system wont appear until I will play with the window (resizing alot in 5-7 seconds), that contains their common parent. If I won't touch this, Particles will work (console.log), but I will not be able to see them at all. It seems like when I am resizing the window or minimize & show back, I am calling something like "repaint" in the window and it's children. It only happens, when I am having item with Canvas. All other items works well with those Particles. Qt5.7, mingw32, Windows 7. Btw, same code works like a charm under Mac OS Sierra. **How to fix this?**

**UPDATE**

As was suggested: pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick widgets
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES +=  main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300
    color: "black"

    TabBorder {
        id: border
        x:5
        y:5
        width: 200
        height: 75
        //Component.onCompleted: border.prepare()
    }
}
```

TabBorder.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: root
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width

    Particles {
        id: particles
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true
        x: 5
        y: 5
        z:2
    }

    /*function prepare() {
        timer.running = true
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        running: false
        interval: 300
        onTriggered: {
            canvas.prepeared = true
        }
    }*/

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        width: parent.width
        height: root.height
        /*property bool prepeared: false
        onPrepearedChanged: requestPaint()*/

        onPaint: {
            //if (canvas.prepeared)
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') //comment this line to make everything works well without timers
        }
    }
}
```

Particles.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Item {
    id: root

    ParticleSystem { id: systemp }
    ImageParticle {
        system: systemp
        source: "qrc:///particleresources/star.png"
        color: "red"
        SequentialAnimation on color {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            ColorAnimation {
                from: "red"
                to: "blue"
                duration: 1000
            }
            ColorAnimation {
                from: "blue"
                to: "red"
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
        colorVariation: 0.3
    }
    Emitter {
        id: trails
        system: systemp
        emitRate: 150
        lifeSpan: 750
        y: 0
        x: 0
        velocity: PointDirection {xVariation: 2; yVariation: 2;}
        acceleration: PointDirection {xVariation: 3; yVariation: 3;}
        velocityFromMovement: 5
        size: 10
        sizeVariation: 5
    }
}
```

My workaround You can check when You uncomment all lines. Without it-> read above.

**UPDATE**

Same issue was discovered in Windows 8.1 with same tools (mingw32, Qt5.7).

Comment: Was just joking on the "cool story". :)  That a nice question, upvoted. Hope someone can shed some light on the issue at hand. I can't do more than upvote, for the moment.

Comment: The code runs fine on Linux. Maybe try setting `layer.enabled: true` for some things as a workaround.

Comment: @Velkan I am not quite sure in which item set this property. I've tried to set just inside Particles, also tried to put in TabBorder + Particles + Canvas. Didn't help. Well, at least, now it's Mac OS and Linux handle this situation well.